# Making an AJAX call from included JavaScript File?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one JSP File and one  JS File .
So inside my JSP File , i have included the JS (Javascript File) like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="HumbleFinance.js"></script>
```

As part of my JSP i have Inside JSP File , I have

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
     url: '/HumblFin/Serv', 
     type: 'GET', 
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType: 'json',
     timeout: 5000,
     success: function(data) { 
      drawChart(data);
   }
```

Now my question is , From the included  JS File , how can i make a call to the jQuery.ajax( function ?? which has been defined in JSP File ??

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Just call it. The only requirement is the the `<script>` element that loads the functions you want must be loaded into the document before you try to call those function.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you added the ajax call. It can be something like this:

```
function callAjax(data){
jQuery.ajax({ 
     url: '/HumblFin/Serv', 
     type: 'GET', 
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: data,
     dataType: 'json',
     timeout: 5000,
     success: function(data) { 
      drawChart(data);
   }
}
```

Now you can call the function `callAjax()` anywhere you want. Obviously inside a javascript file or `<script type="text/javascript">callAjax();</script>` if you're using inline javascript. PS> I've added data as a parameter. Now you can pass the data to the function and it will be passed to the server through ajax call.

Comment: Thank you Naveed , but sometimes i need to pass data to the server with in URL then how to handle this ??